# Login form and accessing pages for admin/users PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication

I created a table which has one admin and can have multiple users. When the user is logged in, he can perform CRUD operations and users can only view the data when they are logged in. BUT there is a problem because i don't know how to omit the regular user from simply entering the address in the address bar and accessing the page he is not supposed to (the page only admin has access to). Since I am new to PHP, I know I am supposed to use sessions for this, but I don't know how. What is the function I need to use, which column from the table (userid or the type - admin and user - those are the user types from the table) and where should I place the if statement in my code?

Comment: Please read any tutorial concerning sessions. Login is the most basic example of sessions and is handled in practically every tutorial.

Comment: First Show your effort, if problem comes, then come to here... dear

Comment: please show what you done, in session you can check user type to access the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `header` and `session`..
when a user logs in .. save his/her `id` in `session variable` lets say `$_SESSION['user_id']`...
and in all the pages which only admin can access put a `if condition` like..

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id'] != '')
{
    $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'Access Denied';
    header('location:user_page.php');
    exit();
}
```

and in `user_page.php` echo that `session error message and unset it`

```
echo $_SESSSION['error_message'];
unset($_SESSION['error_message']);
```

let me know if you want any further guidance..

Comment: I need the user to see only one part of page if he is logged in. For example, I want a poll that I have on my page to be visible only to logged-in users. Can you help me please?

Comment: ohh ok.. than use the same condition like...
`if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id'] != '')
{
  echo 'data to show to the user';
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['admin_id']) && $_SESSION['admin_id'] != '')
{
 echo 'data to show the admin';
}`

Comment: Hey.. if you liked my answer than please Accept it and +1 it.. @user2517370

Answer (score 0):

How do you "log in" your user? You are using core php or some framework? More details please.

Answer (score 0):

In plain vanilla PHP... (Not Zend or Symphony etc)

You can store details in the session, its a global called $_SESSION, and is available when a session is started.

This tutorial may help; http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson12.php

Just remember anything in a session is cleared when your browser is closed - but thats usually a good thing for user activity.

Persistence across browser usage, would be storing the session in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

pass user type to session 
`$_SESSION['usertype'] = $user['usertype'];`
and check the session

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['usertype'] = "user") {  
load  your user page
}
else
{
```

load admin page
    }
    ?>